# Calculate time difference between rows in python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, date-arithmetic

Trying to calculate the time difference between rows if several conditions apply:

```
df['open_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['open_time'], errors='coerce')
df['Time_diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time_diff'], errors='coerce')

for i in range(1, len(df)):
if df.loc[i, 'JOB_ID'] == df.loc[i-1, 'JOB_ID'] and df.loc[i, 'STATION_IDX'] > df.loc[i-1, 'STATION_IDX']:
    df['Time_diff'] = df.loc[i, 'open_time'] - df.loc[i-1, 'open_time']
```

open_time is a simple time in the day HH:mm:ss at which an action was performed, that's all...

The original dataset is:

```
JOB_ID  DDMMYY  STATION_IDX open_time
121663240   04-02-19    25  5:02:19
121663240   04-02-19    26  5:04:00
121663240   04-02-19    27  5:04:42
121651974   04-02-19    25  6:08:15
121651974   04-02-19    27  6:10:28
```

I cannot understand why I keep getting 'NaT' for all the rows of Time_diff

```
       JOB_ID Time_diff
0   121663240       NaT
1   121663240       NaT
2   121663240       NaT
3   121651974       NaT
4   121651974       NaT
5   121682840       NaT
6   121682840       NaT
```

I can't seem to find any answer in Google that will fit my calculation row.

The expected result I hope to get for the above dataset is:

```
JOB_ID ddmmyy   25 to 26    26 to 27    25 to 27
121663240   04-02-2019  101 42  143
121651974   04-02-2019  NaN NaN 133
```

Comment: You were able to show `Time_diff` and `JOB_ID`. Fine untill that. But if you also show `open_time` and `STATION_IDX` you could get relevant answers...

Answer (score 0):

So you just want a new column (`Time_diff`) to contain the difference of column `open_time` between consecutive rows if `JOB_ID` have same value for those 2 rows and STATION_IDX increases.

In pandas, you should try to avoid explicit loops because that is not the way pandas is optimized. Here what you want is probably:

```
# first build a mask for rows having same JOB_ID and STATION_IDX as previous one
mask = (df.JOB_ID==df.JOB_ID.shift())&(df.STATION_IDX>df.STATION_IDX.shift())
# then compute the difference
df.loc[mask,'Time_diff'] = df.loc[mask, 'open_time'] - df.shift().loc[mask, 'open_time']
```

With your sample data, it gives:

```
      JOB_ID    DDMMYY  STATION_IDX           open_time Time_diff
0  121663240  04-02-19           25 2019-07-01 05:02:19       NaT
1  121663240  04-02-19           26 2019-07-01 05:04:00  00:01:41
2  121663240  04-02-19           27 2019-07-01 05:04:42  00:00:42
3  121651974  04-02-19           25 2019-07-01 06:08:15       NaT
4  121651974  04-02-19           27 2019-07-01 06:10:28  00:02:13
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I updated the dataset and tried the above suggestion - the result is still NaT...

Comment: @NirR: Your dataframe has never 2 consecutive lines sharing same JOB_ID and STATION_IDX, so `mask` is a Series of only `False` values. What is the expected result?

Comment: I added the expected result. I'm trying to find out the time between station to station

Comment: @NirR: My bad. I was using `==` between consecutive `STATION_IDX` when it should have been `>`. Fixed.